# How to convert sql query to laravel ORM query, INSERT IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
    public function update_tb_tokenidparc($token, $id_vendedor_pr, $id_corretora_pr, $id_parceiro){" INSERT INTO tb_tokenidparc 
    (nu_cdVendedor4E_tk1,nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk,nu_IdParceiro_tk,cd_Codtokenidparc,status_token)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT $id_vendedor_pr,$id_corretora_pr,$id_parceiro,$token,'1') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tb_tokenidparc WHERE nu_cdVendedor4E_tk = $id_vendedor_pr and nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk = $id_corretora_pr
        and nu_IdParceiro_tk = $id_parceiro and cd_Codtokenidparc = '.$token.') LIMIT 1)";
```

I have this Model and need to convert this to laravel orm

The biggest problem is if not exist clause who i didn't found in laravel docs

If have something like i apreciate

i'm not looking for insert or create because this don't solve my problems

Edit¹: The reason to convert is because i've an array to pass.

Edit²: What i've already tried

```
public function insert_tb_tokenidparc($token, $id_vendedor_pr, $id_corretora_pr, $id_parceiro){

        DB::table('tb_tokenidparc')->firstOrCreate([
            'nu_cdVendedor4E_tk' => $id_vendedor_pr,
            'nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk' => $id_corretora_pr,
            'nu_IdParceiro_tk' => $id_parceiro,
            'cd_Codtokenidparc' => $token,
            'status_token' => '1',
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Replace `....WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tb_tokenidparc...` with `....WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM tb_tokenidparc...`(asterisk with a constant).

Comment: This works... i want to convert to laravel ORM as i wrote in the title.

Comment: What do you mean how? Learn how to learn how to do it by reading the documentation of [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Comment: Have you tried using the [`firstOrCreate` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)?

Comment: Yeah i've tried but still get multiple record with same value.

Comment: @MarcoFalcao could you add the code you tried with `firstOrCreate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `firstOrCreate` method two parameters: the first parameter should contain the column/value pairs that you want to look up and the second any other colum/value pairs that you want to insert when the first column/value pairs aren't found in the database.

In your case it looks like you want to look up all of the column except the `status_token` value, so you could change your usage of the `firstOrCreate` method slightly to:

```
 TbTokenidparc::firstOrCreate([
            'nu_cdVendedor4E_tk' => $id_vendedor_pr,
            'nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk' => $id_corretora_pr,
            'nu_IdParceiro_tk' => $id_parceiro,
            'cd_Codtokenidparc' => $token,
        ], [
            'status_token' => '1',
        ]);
```

Assuming `TbTokenidparc` an Eloquent model for your `tb_tokenidparc` table. If you haven't already defined the model you could define it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TbTokenidparc extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tb_tokenidparc';

     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['nu_cdVendedor4E_tk1', 'nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk', 'nu_IdParceiro_tk', 'cd_Codtokenidparc', 'status_token'];
}
```

Comment: i think i'm doing something wrong , get this error "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrCreate does not exist."

Comment: I used a [code](http://prntscr.com/o91l77) like this and it's working but also thank you for your help i don't knew about `firstOrCreate` at all

Comment: It's a please @MarcoFalcao. `firstOrCreate` does exactly you did in your screenshot. However, it looks like you need to run it on a model class. So if you've defined an Eloquent model for your `tb_tokenidparc` table you can use it on your model class.

Comment: Now it's working ty for your efforts hope u have a nice day